# Bezier path see if it crosses

Tags: objective-c, ios, polygon, uibezierpath

I have a code that lets the user draw a shape, I'm using UIBezierPath for this. But I need to see if the shape crosses itself, for example like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Complex_polygon.svg
Then it's not a a valid shape.
How can I find this?

Edit:
I still haven't solved this. I save all the points between the lines in the path in a array. And then I loop through the array and try to find if any lines intersects. But it does not work, sometimes it says that there is an intersection when it isn't.

I think that the problem is somewhere in this method.

```
-(BOOL)pathIntersects:(double *)x:(double *)y {
int count = pathPoints.count;
CGPoint p1, p2, p3, p4;
for (int a=0; a<count; a++) {

    //Line 1
    if (a+1<count) {
        p1 = [[pathPoints objectAtIndex:a] CGPointValue];
        p2 = [[pathPoints objectAtIndex:a+1] CGPointValue];
    }else{
        return NO;
    }

    for (int b=0; b<count; b++) {

        //Line 2
        if (b+1<count) {
            p3 = [[pathPoints objectAtIndex:b] CGPointValue];
            p4 = [[pathPoints objectAtIndex:b+1] CGPointValue];
        }else{
            return NO;
        }


        if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(p1, p3) && !CGPointEqualToPoint(p2, p3) && !CGPointEqualToPoint(p4, p1) && !CGPointEqualToPoint(p4, p2)
            && !CGPointEqualToPoint(p1, p2) && !CGPointEqualToPoint(p3, p4)) {

            if (LineIntersect(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, p4.x, p4.y, x, y)) { 
                return YES;
            }

        }

    }
}
return NO;
}
```

This is the code I found to see if two lines intersects, It's in C but I should work.

```
int LineIntersect(
              double x1, double y1,
              double x2, double y2,
              double x3, double y3,
              double x4, double y4,
              double *x, double *y)
{
double mua,mub;
double denom,numera,numerb;

denom  = (y4-y3) * (x2-x1) - (x4-x3) * (y2-y1);
numera = (x4-x3) * (y1-y3) - (y4-y3) * (x1-x3);
numerb = (x2-x1) * (y1-y3) - (y2-y1) * (x1-x3);

/* Are the line coincident? */
if (ABS(numera) < 0.00001 && ABS(numerb) < 0.00001 && ABS(denom) < 0.00001) {
    *x = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    *y = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    return(TRUE);
}

/* Are the line parallel */
if (ABS(denom) < 0.00001) {
    *x = 0;
    *y = 0;
    return(FALSE);
}

/* Is the intersection along the the segments */
mua = numera / denom;
mub = numerb / denom;
if (mua < 0 || mua > 1 || mub < 0 || mub > 1) {
    *x = 0;
    *y = 0;
    return(FALSE);
}
*x = x1 + mua * (x2 - x1);
*y = y1 + mua * (y2 - y1);
return(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a polygon like the one in the example or about Bezier curves?

Comment: I'm talking about polygons. I let the user draw a path then I close the path so it becomes a polygon. But if the path crosses itself, then the shape is invalid and must be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how complex the polygon drawn by the user can be and the number of points in the path. Ideally, there would be a point for all the vertices in the shape and nothing more. Get a CGPath from the UIBezierPath and use GCPathApply to hand the elements to a function, which adds each point to an array. Traverse the array with two for loops, one nested in the other, which checks each line segment against every line segment after it using a standard line-line intersection test. As soon as an intersection has been found, break from the loop. Or, if this were a convenience method, return a BOOL. That's the simplest way.

EDIT: Here's an example of a line-line intersection function which returns a BOOL telling you whether or not two segments cross. Pass in the two points that create the first segment followed by the two points that make the second segment. It was hastily modified from a piece of source code I found online quickly, but it works.

```
CGPoint lineSegmentsIntersect(CGPoint L1P1, CGPoint L1P2, CGPoint L2P1, CGPoint L2P2) 
{ 
    float x1 = L1P1.x, x2 = L1P2.x, x3 = L2P1.x, x4 = L2P2.x;
    float y1 = L1P1.y, y2 = L1P2.y, y3 = L2P1.y, y4 = L2P2.y;

    float bx = x2 - x1; 
    float by = y2 - y1; 
    float dx = x4 - x3; 
    float dy = y4 - y3;

    float b_dot_d_perp = bx * dy - by * dx;

    if(b_dot_d_perp == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    float cx = x3 - x1;
    float cy = y3 - y1;
    float t = (cx * dy - cy * dx) / b_dot_d_perp;

    if(t < 0 || t > 1) {
        return NO;
    }

    float u = (cx * by - cy * bx) / b_dot_d_perp;

    if(u < 0 || u > 1) { 
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

You can use it like this.

```
if (lineSegmentsIntersect(lineOnePointOne,lineOnePointTwo,lineTwoPointOne,lineTwoPointTwo)){
     //segments intersect
} else {
     //segments did not intersect
}
```

It's up to you to create the double loop to check the correct segments against one another.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that, I taught of doing that but I wanted to wait if someone had a simpler solution.

Comment: BTW, I don't need to use bezier path. Would it be easier if I used something else, like CGPath. Or can I use something different?

Comment: I stored my path as a CGMutablePathRef property. I don't use UIBezierPath unless I need curves and stuff.

Comment: Hi, I'm haven't had time to test this yet. I will try it today, but what do you mean with "standard line-line intersection test". How can I do this if I have 4 points(2 lines)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fuskaren Sorry I took so long to get back to you. I updated my post with a function you can use. Just hand it the four points and it'll return a BOOL telling you whether or not the lines intersect.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The line intersection code works now. But I can't get it to work with my path. This should be marked as incorrect but it doesn't. http://piclair.com/data/g0nwi.jpg
Could it be if the line segments are to small, they don't count as intersected?

Comment: Nvm, I found the problem. In my code just remove the else statement where I create line 2, point p3 and p4. Thanks for all help!

Comment: Btw, the code is real slow because sometimes its alot of lines to test. At first I had it in the touches moved method but that lags, so now I only test it when the user end the touch. You don't have a solution that doesn't need to loop through the whole path?

Comment: @fuskaren Don't iterate through the whole path every time; just check what's changed. In `touchesMoved`, every time the user moves a finger, I add a point. I then take the line segment formed by this new point and the last and test it against the old line segments. So, every time the user moves their finger I test the newly added segment against all the old ones. If you were to traverse the whole path it'd take around 5000 checks every time they moved a finger if the line was 100 segments long; only doing the new segment against the old would lessen this to 99 checks when their finger moves.

Comment: Thanks I did that, and I found that the lag was caused by having a NSLog in the loop. When I removed it, everything runs smooth.