# How to smooth hand drawn lines?

Tags: math, lines, smoothing

So I am using Kinect with Unity.

With the Kinect, we detect a hand gesture and when it is active we draw a line on the screen that follows where ever the hand is going. Every update the location is stored as the newest (and last) point in a line. However the lines can often look very choppy.

Here is a general picture that shows what I want to achieve:

[image: Smoother versus Rough Lines]

With the red being the original line, and the purple being the new smoothed line. If the user suddenly stops and turns direction, we think we want it to not exactly do that but instead have a rapid turn or a loop.

My current solution is using [Cubic Bezier](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/), and only using points that are X distance away from each other (with Y points being placed between the two points using Cubic Bezier). However there are two problems with this, amongst others:

1) It often doesn't preserve the curves to the distance outwards the user drew them, for example if the user suddenly stop a line and reverse the direction there is a pretty good chance the line won't extend to point where the user reversed the direction.

2) There is also a chance that the selected "good" point is actually a "bad" random jump point.

So I've thought about other solutions. One including limiting the max angle between points (with 0 degrees being a straight line). However if the point has an angle beyond the limit the math behind lowering the angle while still following the drawn line as best possible seems complicated. But maybe it's not. Either way I'm not sure what to do and looking for help.

Keep in mind this needs to be done in real time as the user is drawing the line.

Comment: I think what you actually want is some kind of least squares fitting. Set up a cubic spline and then fit its control points so that the overall squared distance to your curve is minimized.

Comment: see [Approximating data with a multi segment cubic bezier curve and a distance as well as a curvature contraint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22556381/2521214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm to simplify your curve:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

It's a simple algorithm, and parameterization is reasonably intuitive. You may use it as a preprocessing step or maybe after one or more other algorithms. In any case it's a good algorithm to have in your toolbox.

Using angles to reject "jump" points may be tricky, as you've seen. One option is to compare the total length of N line segments to the straight-line distance between the extreme end points of that chain of N line segments. You can threshold the ratio of (totalLength/straightLineLength) to identify line segments to be rejected. This would be a quick calculation, and it's easy to understand.

If you want to take line segment lengths and segment-to-segment angles into consideration, you could treat the line segments as vectors and compute the cross product. If you imagine the two vectors as defining a parallelogram, and if knowing the area of the parallegram would be a method to accept/reject a point, then the cross product is another simple and quick calculation.

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~daddel/linear_algebra_appl/Applications/Determinant/Determinant/node4.html

If you only have a few dozen points, you could randomly eliminate one point at a time, generate your spline fits, and then calculate the point-to-spline distances for all the original points. Given all those point-to-spline distances you can generate a metric (e.g. mean distance) that you'd like to minimize: the best fit would result from eliminating points (Pn, Pn+k, ...) resulting in a spline fit quality S. This technique wouldn't scale well with more points, but it might be worth a try if you break each chain of line segments into groups of maybe half a dozen segments each.

Although it's overkill for this problem, I'll mention that Euler curves can be good fits to "natural" curves. What's nice about Euler curves is that you can generate an Euler curve fit by two points in space and the tangents at those two points in space. The code gets hairy, but Euler curves (a.k.a. aesthetic curves, if I remember correctly) can generate better and/or more useful fits to natural curves than Bezier nth degree splines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral