# Defining piecewise spline cubic curves in 3D

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, curve, spline

I have a set of points `p1, p2, …, pn ,` and I want to define a curve that is go through all the point with continuity of order `C^2` ( *first and second derivative is continuous*).

The proposed solution is to construct a complex curve by piecing together several cubic curves:(*spline curve*).
Each curve segment is a cubic polynomial with its own coefficient.

So in 2D for each segment the cubic polynomial function will be:

```
f_i(x)= a_i +b_i x + c_i x^2 + d_i x^3
```

Posing the following conditions we will be able to find the coefficient `a,b,c,d` for each segment:

[image]

Now if we move to 3D, the best way is to define a parametric spline curve
`f(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))` where x,y, and z is a function of the parameter t.

[image]

Then by assigning to each provided point p1, …, pn the t parameter t1, … tn Then we can find all the coefficient  and the problem is solved.

Then my question is:
If I want to use a parametric spline curve `f(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))` still I need to define the t1, … , tn values ? What will be the perfect way to define them?(chord length ?)

Otherwise I have to used an explicit function ( without adding this t parameter) like the way I use it in 2D example above:
`y=h(x),` and `z=g(x)`.

However explicit functions presentation has disadvantages one of them is infinite slope is difficult to represent?

So what do you suggest to do ?

Comment: There is no perfect way and it depends on the nature of your data. A good option might be to use the relative distance of your control points.

Comment: Thanks @NicoSchertler . You mean using a parametric spline curve and defining t1= ||p2-p1||, t2=||p3-p2|| and so on ? if it is the case, what would be the impact of this on the final curve ?

Comment: Well, not exactly. If `L` is the total length of the control poly-line, then: `t1 = 0, t2 = ||p2-p1|| / L, t3=(||p3-p2||+||p2_p1|)|/L, ...` This will make the curve to have approximately uniform velocity. Just try it. The division by `L` is not necessary but just a convenience to get parameters in the [0, 1] range.

Comment: Yes this is one solution, I will try it. However, I wonder what will be the impact of this on the final curve because to have a uniform velocity we should calculate t1,t2, ..,tn in term of the arc length and not the euclidean distance {  t1= (arc legnth of p1p2) /(arc length of all the curve) }, so what we are doing is an approximation, which seems to be the best things we can do in this case.

Comment: If you really need near-perfect uniform velocity, you can iterate. I.e. start with a guess from the Euclidean distances. Once you have the spline, measure the distance on this and refine the parameters. Loop until convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicoSchertler

Comment: see [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214) and the sublinks especially the last [Interpolation cubic vs. Bezier cubic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) may be it will help you a bit