# How to draw a bezier curve WITHOUT knowing its control points, but four points on the curve?

Tags: .net, graphics, bezier

I am developing a graphical editor application. It has a Bezier tool. I want to implement it similar to the bezier control in Paint.NET application, where two handles of the curve (in addition to the end points) **are placed on the curve itself**, by which the user can control the curvature. Placement of these handles on the curve, gives a better sense and feel to the graphist, as is shown in this figure:[image]

But my problem is that DrawBezier method in .NET, gets two **control points** that are not guaranteed to be always placed on the curve.
Do you know how can I use the coordinates of these two **on-curve handles** to draw a Bezier?

Comment: If the *parameter values* (roughly equivalent to the distance along the curve) of these points are unknown, then you have 4 equations with 6 unknowns (in 2D), which is *under-determined* i.e. there are infinitely many Bezier curves that fit these 4 points. In Paint.NET these points probably correspond to *known* parameters e.g. `t=1/3` and `t=2/3`, in which case the problem is deterministic and the curve equation can be solved to obtain the control points.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Would you please specify those 6 equations?

Comment: 4 equations and 6 unknowns, not 6 equations. The unknowns are the XY components of the two on-curve handles (x 4) and their corresponding Bezier parameters (x 2).

Comment: Okay, after some digging into OpenPDN (the open-source fork of Paint.NET), it seems that the curve in question is in-fact **not** a cubic Bezier, but an interpolated cubic spline. Their implementation draws the curve "manually" as a series of straight lines. Go to https://github.com/rivy/OpenPDN/ and search for `SplineInterpolator`. Paint.NET does use Bezier curves elsewhere, but they are drawn by direct calls to GDI+ which require control points, and nowhere are these control points being computed.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thank you very much. I will give it a look. Thanks again.

Comment: You can handle your points as interpolation cubic curve (or catmul rom) ... using this [interpolation -> Bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) you simply convert the points into BEZIER control points. However you need to use parameter `t=<-1,+1>` or use 3 BEZIER patches instead (by mirroring the missing control points) ... however such conversion might not copy the curve exactly ...

Comment: You can use standard polynomial curve fitting (see https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#curvefitting for instance, yielding the pretty similar looking https://i.imgur.com/HOjp4lh.png) but you're always going to have *some* free parameters because you don't just "not know the control points", you _also_ don't know which time values those two on-curve points you do have belong to.

Answer (score 1):

We can use standard polynomial curve fitting to find a single cubic Bezier curve through any set of four points, but you're always going to be left with a free parameter problem: two of the points are going to be the start and end of the curve, so we know their time values are 0 and 1, but the two points are entirely free in terms of time value, and so you're going to have to come up with a reasonable assumption on what they should be before you can evaluate your curve fit.

See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#curvefitting for the maths if you want to implement this yourself, or find a library that does polynomial fitting (which means any half-decent statistics package), and then for timing values you have a few options:

- Assume the points line up with t=0, t=1/3, t=2/3, and t=1. This is almost always a bad idea because points are rarely evenly spaced with respects to the cubic distribution.
- Guess the t values based on linear distance, with the full length of the polyline p0-p1-p2-p3 set to 1, and the value at each point simply equal to the distance along the polyline, so t0=0, t1=dist(p0,p1), t2=dist(p0,p1)+dist(p1,2), t3=1.
- Get fancier and pick an initial set of t values, then analyze the resulting Bezier and iteratively generate new curves, optimizing on some quality like curvature homogeneity, bounding box/hull area, aligning p1/p2 on minimum radius, etc.

Of these, obviously 2 is going to give "reasonable" results with the least amount of effort, but if you're writing a graphics application, "reasonable" depends on what your users need, not what is easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

The **DrawCurve** method of the Graphics class does the job. That is, instead of using Bezier curves, you should use Canonical Spline.

I found it in **Charles Petzold**'s book (Programming Windows with C#):

*"The Canonical Spline - The Graphic class includes a second type of spline called the canonical spline, meaning a standard or normal spline..."*

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrates that this indeed does the job? Otherwise this is more of a comment than an answer.