# How to create bezier curves for an arc with different start and end tangent slopes

Tags: c#, math, geometry, bezier, curve

I've been stuck on this for a week now i can't seem to solve it.

I have an arc which i can convert to a series of bezier curves quite easily when the arc is flat:

[image]

But i am struggling to work out how to find the bezier curves when the arc is a helix and the end tangents have different slopes.

This is as far as i have gotten so far:

[image]

As you can see each bezier curve has control points that are not on the right plane, and the start and end tangent (the red vectors in the second image) of the full arc is not factored in as i couldn't work out how to do it.

To find the flat version of the bezier slices from arcs i have this piece of code which certainly works fine for a flat arc:

```
    // from https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic
    public CubicBezier ConvertArc(Vector3 origin, float radius, Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float angle)
    {
        var c = Math.Tan(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad / 4f) * 4 / 3f * radius;

        var c1 = from + (from - origin).Perp().normalized * c;
        var c2 = to - (to - origin).Perp().normalized * c;
        return new CubicBezier(from, c1, c2, to);
    }
```

This is my current code to create each bezier cut:

```
        //cut the arc in to bezier curves up to 90 degrees max
        float cuts = _arc.totalAngle / 90f;
        for (int i = 0; i < cuts; i++)
        {
            float t = i / cuts;
            float t2 = (i + 1) / cuts;

            Arc slice = new Arc(_arc,_arc.Point(t),_arc.Point(t2));

            //this function below is the issue, it needs start and end tangent for the slice, 
            //but i also don't know how to find the tangents at each slice for the whole arc
            //relating the start and end tangents of the entire arc
            //see above snippet for function code
            var cb = ConvertArc(slice.origin, slice.radius, slice.a, slice.b, slice.totalAngle);
            cb.DebugDraw(Color.yellow);
        }
```

Hope some one can help explain the logic to solve how to find the control points correctly to match the tangents, wasted a week already with little progress.

This is written in C# but i don't think the language matters, math is math no matter the language.

A visual (albeit poor drawing) of how i want the result to respect the end tangent slopes:
[image]

Comment: take a look at this [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)  especially the link [Interpolation cubic vs. Bezier cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) yuo can sample your helix points directly and convert them to BEZIER by the equations there

Comment: Most of the examples are in 2d and its confusing me how to interpolate between the two tangents at final end points, I tired all week such as interpolating between the end tangent slopes but that didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you do not need to interpolate anything ... you just set some points and the interpolation cubic will make smooth path for you ... start end tangent direction is made by the first and last control point of the path ... porting to any Dimensionality is not a problem as the equation is the same. Would you like a simple example? but in C++ I do not code in C#

Comment: Example would be great, you can use pseduo code, as long as I understand the logic I can intepret it to try it out and understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Bezier control points are not as intuitive as interpolation cubics.  So we can use those instead and convert their control points into bezier later to make thing easier.

1. **Simply create list of points along your path**

   all of these are directly on the path and the continuity of the curve is guaranteed by the interpolation cubic equation itself so no tweaking needed...

   be sure you have enough points ... for example for full circle at least 8 points are needed nut 16 are better ...
2. **Convert path points into Bezier cubic control points**

   so simply pick 4 consequent points on path and convert them into bezier control points using this:

   - [Interpolation cubic vs. Bezier cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214)

   to ensure continuity the next bezier should be done from next point ... So if we have points p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5... then we create beziers from `(p0,p1,p2,p3)` , `(p1,p2,p3,p4)` , ... and so on. The first point `p0` determines starting direction and the last the ending one. If you want your path to start / end on those simply duplicate them ...

**Here a small unoptimized and crude example of this in C++:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
List<double> it4;   // interpolation cubic control points
List<double> bz4;   // bezier cubic control points
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void generate()
    {
    int i,j,n;
    double x,y,z,a,a0,a1,z0,z1,da,dz,r;
    const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
    const double rad=180.0/M_PI;

    // generate some helix path points
    n=32;                           // number of points along path
    r=0.75;                         // radius
    z0=0.0; z1=0.5;                 // height range
    a0=-25.0*deg; a1=+720.0*deg;    // angle range
    da=(a1-a0)/double(n);
    dz=(z1-z0)/double(n);
    it4.num=0;  // clear list of points
    for (z=z0,a=a0,i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da,z+=dz)
        {
        // 3D point on helix
        x=r*cos(a);
        y=r*sin(a);
        // add it to the list
        it4.add(x);
        it4.add(y);
        it4.add(z);
        }

    // convert it4 into bz4 control points
    bz4.num=0;  // clear list of points
    for (i=0;i<=it4.num-12;i+=3)
        {
        const double m=1.0/6.0;
        double x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3;
        double X0,Y0,Z0,X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3;
        j=i;
        X0=it4[j]; j++; Y0=it4[j]; j++; Z0=it4[j]; j++;
        X1=it4[j]; j++; Y1=it4[j]; j++; Z1=it4[j]; j++;
        X2=it4[j]; j++; Y2=it4[j]; j++; Z2=it4[j]; j++;
        X3=it4[j]; j++; Y3=it4[j]; j++; Z3=it4[j]; j++;
        x0 = X1;           y0 = Y1;           z0 = Z1;
        x1 = X1-(X0-X2)*m; y1 = Y1-(Y0-Y2)*m; z1 = Z1-(Z0-Z2)*m;
        x2 = X2+(X1-X3)*m; y2 = Y2+(Y1-Y3)*m; z2 = Z2+(Z1-Z3)*m;
        x3 = X2;           y3 = Y2;           z3 = Z2;
        bz4.add(x0); bz4.add(y0); bz4.add(z0);
        bz4.add(x1); bz4.add(y1); bz4.add(z1);
        bz4.add(x2); bz4.add(y2); bz4.add(z2);
        bz4.add(x3); bz4.add(y3); bz4.add(z3);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And simple render in VCL/GL/C++**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-2.5);
    glRotatef(-70.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(-130.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    int i,j;
    // render axises
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3d(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex3d(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glEnd();


    // render it4 control points (aqua)
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,1.0);
    glPointSize(8);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0;i<it4.num;i+=3) glVertex3dv(it4.dat+i);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1);

    // render bz4 control points (magenta)
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0);
    glPointSize(4);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0;i<bz4.num;i+=3) glVertex3dv(bz4.dat+i);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1);

    // render bz4 path (yellow)
    double t,tt,ttt,cx[4],cy[4],cz[4],x,y,z;
    double x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3;
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glLineWidth(2);
    for (i=0;i<=bz4.num-12;i+=12)
        {
        j=i;
        x0=bz4[j]; j++; y0=bz4[j]; j++; z0=bz4[j]; j++;
        x1=bz4[j]; j++; y1=bz4[j]; j++; z1=bz4[j]; j++;
        x2=bz4[j]; j++; y2=bz4[j]; j++; z2=bz4[j]; j++;
        x3=bz4[j]; j++; y3=bz4[j]; j++; z3=bz4[j]; j++;
        cx[0]=                            (    x0);
        cx[1]=                   (3.0*x1)-(3.0*x0);
        cx[2]=          (3.0*x2)-(6.0*x1)+(3.0*x0);
        cx[3]= (    x3)-(3.0*x2)+(3.0*x1)-(    x0);
        cy[0]=                            (    y0);
        cy[1]=                   (3.0*y1)-(3.0*y0);
        cy[2]=          (3.0*y2)-(6.0*y1)+(3.0*y0);
        cy[3]= (    y3)-(3.0*y2)+(3.0*y1)-(    y0);
        cz[0]=                            (    z0);
        cz[1]=                   (3.0*z1)-(3.0*z0);
        cz[2]=          (3.0*z2)-(6.0*z1)+(3.0*z0);
        cz[3]= (    z3)-(3.0*z2)+(3.0*z1)-(    z0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (t=0.0,j=0;j<20;j++,t+=0.05)
            {
            tt=t*t; ttt=tt*t;
            x=cx[0]+cx[1]*t+cx[2]*tt+cx[3]*ttt;
            y=cy[0]+cy[1]*t+cy[2]*tt+cy[3]*ttt;
            z=cz[0]+cz[1]*t+cz[2]*tt+cz[3]*ttt;
            glVertex3d(x,y,z);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    glLineWidth(1);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also used mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

just to be sure the code is comprehensable.

And preview:

[image: preview]

When you want to edit your path its better to control the interpolation cubic control points instead of the bezier as you learned the hard way those are not as intuitive and easy to manipulate to achieve wanted output.

**[Edit1] input points better matching your shape**

As you finally provided image of shape you want ... you simply sample some points along the path and convert that into bezier. So the only stuff that changes are the input points:

```cpp
void generate()
    {
    int i,j,n;
    double x,y,z,a,a0,a1,b,b0,b1,z0,dz,r,t;
    const double deg=M_PI/180.0;
    const double rad=180.0/M_PI;

    // generate some helix path points
    n=32;                           // number of points along path
    r=0.75;                         // curve radius
    z0=0.0;                         // mid height
    dz=0.1;                         // height amplitude
    a0=180.0*deg; a1=   0.0*deg;    // angle range
    b0= 30.0*deg; b1=+330.0*deg;    // angle range
    it4.num=0;  // clear list of points
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        // parameters
        t=double(i)/double(n-1);
        a=a0+(a1-a0)*t;
        b=b0+(b1-b0)*t;
        // curve
        x=r*cos(a);
        y=r*sin(a);
        // height
        z=z0+dz*sin(b);
        // add it to the list
        it4.add(x);
        it4.add(y);
        it4.add(z);
        }

    // convert it4 into bz4 control points
    bz4.num=0;  // clear list of points
    for (i=0;i<=it4.num-12;i+=3)
        {
        const double m=1.0/6.0;
        double x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3;
        double X0,Y0,Z0,X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3;
        j=i;
        X0=it4[j]; j++; Y0=it4[j]; j++; Z0=it4[j]; j++;
        X1=it4[j]; j++; Y1=it4[j]; j++; Z1=it4[j]; j++;
        X2=it4[j]; j++; Y2=it4[j]; j++; Z2=it4[j]; j++;
        X3=it4[j]; j++; Y3=it4[j]; j++; Z3=it4[j]; j++;
        x0 = X1;           y0 = Y1;           z0 = Z1;
        x1 = X1-(X0-X2)*m; y1 = Y1-(Y0-Y2)*m; z1 = Z1-(Z0-Z2)*m;
        x2 = X2+(X1-X3)*m; y2 = Y2+(Y1-Y3)*m; z2 = Z2+(Z1-Z3)*m;
        x3 = X2;           y3 = Y2;           z3 = Z2;
        bz4.add(x0); bz4.add(y0); bz4.add(z0);
        bz4.add(x1); bz4.add(y1); bz4.add(z1);
        bz4.add(x2); bz4.add(y2); bz4.add(z2);
        bz4.add(x3); bz4.add(y3); bz4.add(z3);
        }
    }
```

Here preview:

[image: preview N=32]

And preview with N=8 points:

[image: preview N=8]

I simply separated curve and height into circular path with parameter `a` and sinusoid with parameter `b`. As you can see the conversion code is the same no matter the change of input points ...

Comment: Are you sure this also factors in the different slopes for each end of a helical arc? (My arc doesn't exceed 360 degrees) but the start tangent might be sloping up, the end tangent might be sloping down. Where as your solution seems to suggest a constant slope through out the whole curve?

Comment: Also its not obvious to me how you are finding the control points of the cubic bezier curve, rather you seem to be interpolating along the line itself..not too familiar with that approach as my whole setup involves using control points to maintain tangents between cubic splines.

Comment: Maybe this drawing might help explain what i meant by the slopes at each end of the helical arc: https://imgur.com/jNYBohA in that they don't have the same direction in this drawing for example they both slope downwards.

Comment: @WDUK 1. what points you feed that shape you got I just used simple helix if you want different you do different. Didnt bother with that as you are editing the points manually anyway  2. computation from it4 to bz4 is done by algebraically comparing the cubic polynomial coefficients and deriving bz4 coefficients from it4 control points (`X0,Y0,...`) instead of bz4 control points (`x0,y0,...`). That is the code formatted stuff in the bottom of the first link in my answer. Its pure algebra... and you can just use the final equation like I did.

Comment: @WDUK I added edit1 with better match. btw if you got a terrain map it might be better to use 2D track/path/road whatever shape and convert that to 3D it4 points by projecting/maping them onto the surface directly ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been trying understand the code but it's a bit difficult to follow. My api takes two end points and two control points to define a bezier curve rather than interpolating a series of points along the curve so I'm not sure if your approach will match the way my library does it.

Comment: @WDUK if you have the the equation to solve the cubic coefficients for your curve then you can compute the conversion in the same way as i did ...  so try to find out what curve exactly your lib uses May its [Ferguson curve](http://evlm.stuba.sk/~velichova/Geometria/PREDNASKY/lecture4.htm) instead of Bezier

Answer (score 0):

You have some segment of 3d curve with known tangents at endpoints and want to build Bezier approximation.

Inner control points of Bezier curve will lie on vectors collinear with tangent vectors. But you need to know their length.

Approximation approach for circle arc chooses such length of these vectors to provide middle Bezier point coinciding with middle point of arc. You can apply the same method here. Write

```
P1 = P0 + T0 * L
P2 = P3 - T3 * L
```

substitute in Bezier equation with t=1/2, P = middle of the curve and find unknown L. Make this for all three components and get some average providing rather good error (perhaps some optimization is possible).

If curve is highly unsymmetric - someone may try to use different lengths for both tangents.

Comment: Are you sure it is linear on z if the helix has different end tangent slopes? (the red vectors). When I tried learping linearly the slopes it was totally broken. I'll show you the result when I get home to show what I mean.

Comment: It is linear for perfect helix. Seems your curve is not, in this case my answer is improper and I will remove it after you read this. Subdivide curve into segments and apploximate every with Bezier with control points based on tangents

Comment: Your suggestion is basically what i am saying i am struggling to solve in my question. I can't figure out the control point positions with the tangents taken into account.

Comment: The controls are tangent to the arc but they don't have the right slopes. If you see my second image in my question, the two red lines at the ends of the arc are the tangents at each end of the arc, i can pitch them up and down but i can't calculate the series of bezier curves that match these pitches in tangents as bezier curves.

Comment: For curve segment you have end points and tangents (unit vectors). To provide correct Bezier direction at the ends, control points **must** lie on the tangents, you cannot choose arbitrary points. But  distances endpoint-controlpoint are unknown, we have to fit them to provide good approximation.

Comment: Yeah but finding where the control points should be exactly along the curve at each curve slice was the hard part i could not figure out. I tried simply lerping between the two end tangent unit vectors but that didn't work because it doesn't respect the fact i'm interpolating a curve.

Comment: I proposed euristic approach. It should work for "nice" curves. (mainly symmetric)

Comment: Do you know how do approximation of quarter-of-circle by Bezier work?

Comment: Yes the code is in my question but it only works for a quarter circle that is flat.

Comment: The same approach - calculating tangent length to provide proximity of middle points -  should work for 3D (perhaps worse)