# Javascript: How would you approach created a blob that can be modified by sliding nodes along an axis

Tags: javascript, graphics, slider, nodes

I am looking for tips on how to approach creating an editable graphic that looks like a pie chart and can be modified by sliding nodes along specific axes.  The resulting graphic would look like the image below (created in illustrator).

[image]

The closest I have come to finding something similar is a windrose chart.

[image]

I have thought of using Bezier.js or something similar but wondering if anyone might know of an existing library that might get close to what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: closed [piece wise interpolation cubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214) (might be [emulated by BEZIER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214) or SPLINE) bounded by some circle ... that way the control point will behave as on your image. The color is dependend just on radius so either 1D texture or parametric SW gradient

Comment: For the color I think I could possibly use a mask if that is an option and it is just an underlying graphic or gradiante object.  I'll look into the other tips.  Thanks!